# How do I retrieve a list item's x,y coordinates in relation to its parent <ul>

Tags: jquery, dom, traversal

Ideally I would like to have a list like this:

```
<ul class="parent" id="app1">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <ul class="child">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1 - 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to know the x,y coordinate of the `<li>` after its clicked.

```
$('.parent > li').click( function() {

  var x = $(this)...  // x coordinate
  var y = $(this)...  // y coordinate
  var sub_y = y + $(this).height();
  var sub_x = x; // want x to be 0 (left side of ul.parent)

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See the demo->](http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/f22Hf/)

Use `.position()`:

```
$('.parent > li').click( function() {
  var pos = $(this).position();
  var x = pos.left;  // x coordinate
  var y = pos.top;  // y coordinate
  var sub_y = y + $(this).height();
  var sub_x = x; // want x to be 0 (left side of ul.parent)
  alert(x + ', ' + y);
});
```

This will allow you to get the computed top and left position of the element.

Comment: Thanks! I remember seeing this before...  but had no use for it at the time.  Now that I need the function, I forget it exists.  Go figure.  Also can I do pos.bottom to get the computed bottom of the element?

Comment: No, `.position()` only has top and left.  Add the height of the element (use `.height()`) to the top to get the bottom position.

Comment: Thats what I thought which is why you see "sub_y = y + $(this).height()"  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.parent > li').click( function() {
    var x = $(this).offset().left;  // x coordinate
    var y = $(this).offset().top;  // y coordinate

    var px = $(this).parent().offset().left;
    var py = $(this).parent().offset().top;

    var rel_x = x - px;
    var rel_y = y - py;
});
```

[On JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6V5gf/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [jQuery postion()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var x = $(this).offset().left;
  var y = $(this).offset().top;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call [position](http://jqapi.com/#p=position) to get the position of an element, relative to its parent.